# Loading My Own themes in VSTO Addin, PowerPoint

Tags: c#, vsto, themes, powerpoint

Hi I have Developped a VSTO Addin for office 2007> and a commandbar object model addin for same application to support office 2003.

in the VSTO Version i want to publish my own Themes through my application. and whenever PowerPoint is open and my addin is loaded, i want my custom themes to come in the  design gallery? is it possible to do it through code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Office Ribbon unfortunately does not allow access to design galleries.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942866(VS.80).aspx